# Firebase how to filter results that exist in another node?

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to get friends' UIDs from a list of UIDs, to implement the same feature in my app as in Instagram that would say "Your friend A, B, and 100 others have liked your post". Is there a way to do such filtering in Firebase? Currently I just read the whole list and do the filtering on client side. But this could potentially consume large amount of data.

```
users
    user1
        friends
            user2
            user3
            ...

posts
    post1
        likes
            user2
            user10
        ...
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you considered changing your datastructure?

Comment: I have certainly tried, but cannot think of a data structure that would work for all users. Do you have any recommendations

Comment: Hey @AndréKool, do you still have any thoughts to share with me?